# Is there a good reason why continuity assumed in the definition of differentiability in do Carmo?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I am reading Do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces.* He defines differentiability as follows:

> A **continuous** map [emphasis mine] $\varphi: V_1 \subset S_1 \to S_2$ of an open set $V_1$ of a regular surface to a regular surface $S_2$ is said to be *differentiable at $p \in V_1$* if, given parametrizations
> $$x_1 : U_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_1 \quad x_2 : U_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_2 $$
> with $p \in x_1(U_1)$ and $\varphi(x_1(U_1)) \subset x_2(U_2),$ the map
> $$x_2^{-1} \circ \varphi \circ x_1:U_1 \to U_2$$
> is differentiable at $q = x_1^{-1}(p)$.

I believe that when he says continuous, and when he says that $V_1$ is open, he is referring to the topologies inherited from $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I was wondering why he assumes $\varphi$ to be **continuous** in the definition. I thought that it must be an easy consequence that $\varphi$ is continuous, if you know that all maps of the form $x_2^{-1} \circ \varphi \circ x_1$ are differentiable (hence continuous).

However, I am starting to think that the continuity requirement is not superfluous. I think that for the definition to be correct, we must do one of two things. Either

1. Assume $\varphi$ is continuous.
2. In the definition, change "given parametrizations" to "there exist parametrizations".

If we do neither, then I think there can be very badly behaved, discontinuous functions $\varphi$ where it is impossible to find parametrizations $x_1, x_2$ with $\varphi(x_1(U_1)) \subset x_2(U_2)$. Hence, $\varphi$ would vaccuously be a diffeomorphism, even though it is discontinuous.

However, if we do drop continuity but make change in $2$, I think we can prove that $\varphi$ is continuous, and we get an equivalent definition to do Carmo's.

Is my analysis above correct?

**EDIT:**

**Proposition:** Let $\varphi$ be *any* function from $S_1$ to $S_2$. If for each point $p \in S_1$ there exist parametrizations $$x_1 : U_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_1 \quad x_2 : U_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S_2 $$
with $p \in x_1(U_1)$ and $\varphi(x_1(U_1)) \subset x_2(U_2)$ such that the map
$$x_2^{-1} \circ \varphi \circ x_1:U_1 \to U_2$$
is differentiable at $q = x_1^{-1}(p),$ then $\varphi$ is a continuous map from $S_1 \to S_2$ (with the topologies inherited from $\mathbb{R}^3$).

$\textit{Proof: }$ Fix $p \in S_1$ and take parametrizations $x_1, x_2,$ and the point $q$, as given in the claim. We will show that $\varphi$ is continuous at $p$.

Let $O_{S_2}$ be any open subset of $S_2$ containing $\varphi(p)$, and let $O_{U_2} = x_2^{-1}(O_{S_2})$, which is open because (by definition of parametrization) $x_2$ is a homeomorphism.

Now $x_2 ^{-1} \circ \varphi \circ x_1$ is differentiable at $q$, so it is continuous at $q$. Since $O_{U_2}$ contains $x_2 ^{-1} \circ \varphi \circ x_1(q)$, there exists an open subset $O_{U_1}$ of $U_1$, containing $q$, such that $x_2 ^{-1} \circ \varphi \circ x_1 (O_{U_1}) \subseteq O_{U_2}.$ Applying $x_2$ to both sides, we get $\varphi \circ x_1 (O_{U_1}) \subseteq x_2(O_{U_2}) = O_{S_2}.$

Finally, let $O_{S_1} = x_1(U_1)$, which is open because $x_1$ is a homeomorphism. Substituting above, we have $\varphi(O_{S_1}) \subseteq O_{S_2}$, which shows that $\varphi$ is continuous at $p$. Since $p$ was arbitrary, $\varphi$ is continuous on $S_1.$

Comment: It is all fine until the penultimate paragraph: where did a homeomorphism come from here?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah sorry, I just meant continuous, not a homeomorphism. Is it all good now?

Comment: No, it is still not good. Try to write a formal proof of continuity with your proposed definition to see where things go wrong.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for the suggestion. I have written a proof above in an edit, and I cannot see any error or gap. Could you please take a look?

Comment: The mistake is subtle, it is in the sentence "Applying $x_2$ to both sides..." Here is an example: Pick two distinct points $p_2, p_2'\in S_2$ and let $\varphi(p)=p_2$ and $\varphi(p')=p_2'$ for all $p'\ne p$. Take a chart at $p_2$ such that $x_2(U_2)$ does not contain $p_2'$ (here I am using your formulation "there exist parameterizations..."). Now, run your proof with this example to see where it fails. The map $\varphi$ satisfies your conditions but is not continuous.

Comment: @MoisheKohan One of my conditions is that $\varphi(x_1(U_1)) \subseteq x_2(U_2)$. Now $x_1(U_1)$ is an open set containing $p$, so it must contain other points $p' \in S_1$ with $p' \not = p$, and $\varphi$ sends these points to $p_2'$. Therefore, $p_2'$ must be in $x_2(U_2)$, if my conditions are to be satisfied. So it seems to me that this example does not satisfy my conditions.

As for the sentence "Applying $x_2$ to both sides..." I think I am using only set theory, and not using any topology, so it is mysterious to me where in this sentence an error can hide.

Comment: It was unclear to me that this is one of your conditions, I thought it was one of do Carmo's conditions. With this condition  your proof is correct.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Oh okay, thank you very much discussing this with me. This is indeed one of Carmo's conditions. I reproduced it in my post, and it is on page 75 of his book. Anyway, I learned a lot by writing out everything in detail, thanks again.